Can I hide the "Previous Highlighted Error" and "Next Highlighted Error" buttons in WebStorm?
I'm trying to make my WebStorm really minimal.
I'm wondering, is it possible to hide "Previous Highlighted Error" and "Next Highlighted Error" buttons from the top-right side of the window? I know the shortcuts, after all, so I'm not using them :P. To be clear, I also still want to show the number of errors / warnings in the file – that part is okay.
For reference, here's a screenshot of my IDE (when in a tiny window).

I'm just thinking that I could make it 1% more minimal by hiding the 2 buttons in the top right.
So is this possible? Thanks!

Yes, you can configure the Inspection Widget.
According to the docs:
"The widget has a simplified view. To enable it, hover over the widget, click the More button, and select Compact View."
You may need to hover over the part that has the number of errors/warnings.
The "More button" is the three dots to the right of the Inspection Widget.
I just tried this in IntelliJ IDEA (because that's what I use):

WebStorm should work similarly.

Amazing! Thank you! I don't think I'd have found this myself.

You're welcome! I also learned something new today ;)
